# How SSH Tunnel from Windows VM to the host system, which is running Mac

Tags: windows, macos, ssh, openssh, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to ssh tunnel from a Windows VM to the host system, which is running Mac.

I am running this command:

```
ssh -L 80:localhost:5454 10.0.2.2
```

It then prompts me three times for a password like this:

```
Password:
Password:
Password:
```

Each time I enter my password for the windows vm, and it then prompts me for another password:

```
John Smith@10.0.2.2's password:
```

Now this I think is the password I am using for my Mac host system, but it says permission denied and thats it.

So my question is what are these passwords referring to? My ssh password? Even though I have never set one of these up.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have not specified otherwise - you are trying to use your Windows username to authenticate on the Mac.

I assume these username are not *exactly* the same.

From the Mac run

```
whoami
```

Which will print out your exact username, then from Windows, add that username in front of the IP when connecting.

```
ssh macUser@10.0.2.2
    /\
```

You will then be prompted for the password of the user on the mac.

Comment: great that worked thanks!